# Why the installation of MVC3 takes so much time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, installation

I've installed MVC3 already a couple of time on different machines. It takes ages till it's installed. I don't understand why it takes all that times as it seems to install just a few Assemblies. Does anyone knows more about it?